# How to update All Tab Navigation title dynamically?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-tabnavigator

I have 3 Tabs Tab1, Tab2 and Tab3. How can I Change this Tab title dynamically form any tab.

Below is My Code..

```js
const TabNav = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        TabName1: {
            header: null,
            screen: StackNav1,
            navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
                title: 'Tab1',
                header: null,
                tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => {
                    return;
                }
            })
        },
        TabName2: {
            header: null,
            screen: StackNav2,
            navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
                title: 'Tab2'
            })
        },
        TabName3: {
            screen: StackNav3,
            navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
                header: null,
                title: 'Tab3'
            })
        }
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: "TabName1",
        tabBarPosition: "bottom",
        headerMode: "none",
        swipeEnabled: false,
        animationEnabled: false,
        lazy: true,
        removeClippedSubviews: true,
        order: ["TabName1", "TabName2", "TabName3"],
        backBehavior: "initialRoute",
    }
);
```

Please help me how can change Tab title dynamically.

Thanks,

Comment: are you using redux ?

Comment: No. I'm not using redux.

Comment: the only way I know to achieve that ... is through redux unfortunately